# Stucked on embedding my SWF flash file in ASP.NET MVC 3, any Display Template available?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

I have a flash swf file that I want to embed in a view in ASP.NET MVC3 project. I found there are many error prone java-script procedure to do that as if I would have done in plain html. But I am wondering there should be some clean helper, HTML extension method or Display Template available for embedding the swf content. I searched a lot in Google but did not find any. Would anyone please help me pointing out any extension/display template for flash swf file embedding ?

Even if you can point me a solution that is commercial, I wont mind to pay. Rather I am looking for a very rich customizable library what can be highly likely to be commercial.

Comment: You haven't stated what benefits you hope to derive by a commercial plugin, other than improved stability; Flash is intended to be embedded via Javascript, so your claims about instability seem dubious.  See http://www.google.com/#q=embedding+flash+using+javascript

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. Actually, I was wondering there should be some Extension or Display Template for embedding flash so that I can directly pass the name of swf flash file. I tried using manual javascript way but very easily i lost patience when I found some javascript errors, moreoever, I would like to keep javascripts within an encapsulated user control template. Anyway, thank you for the google keyword, I am still searching. My main preference for the extension/template is to pass
1. Flash file name.
2. Height,
3. Width,
4. Alternative HTML (if flash plugin is not available)

Comment: I think, I got a solution here : http://www.codevoyeur.com/Articles/15/ASP.NET-MVC-HtmlHelper-Extensions-for-the-JW-FLV-Media-Player.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ASP.NET MVC HtmlHelper Extensions for the JW FLV Media Player** 
http://www.codevoyeur.com/Articles/15/ASP.NET-MVC-HtmlHelper-Extensions-for-the-JW-FLV-Media-Player.aspx

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you very much for the help. Yes, I got it. Regards.